# Equation of a certain region inside a regular polygon of $n$ .

Tags: analytic-geometry

Consider a regular polygon   $A_1A_2....A_n$ of n sides with unit side length.Without loss of generality  we can take  $A_1$ coincident with  the origin **O** and $A_2$  on positive x axis s.t. $A_1A_2=1$.If $D$ in the region in the polygon with the property that each of the points of  $D$ is closer to the centre of the polygon than to any of the $n$ sides ,it is required to find the equation and the  area of  $D$ .Lots of thanks in anticipation of help

Comment: The boundary of region $D$ is the n-sided regular polygon obtained by shrinking (applying an homothety) in a ratio 1/2 the initial polygon. Thus the ratio of areas is 1/4. It remains to compute the area of a regular polygon with unit side...